# Replacing wall sconce (that has on/off swtich) with ones that do not. Need options for control

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, light-fixture

I have several very old wall sconces that have their own individual on/off toggle switches that I would like to switch out.  Unfortunately there is no wall switch that will allow for control of these.  I have found some wireless receiver controllers that might work - X10, EnOcean.  I wanted to see what people's opinions were/prior experiences with these devices.  I'm also open to any suggestions short of rewiring everything.  That will be done but we're not ready for a major remodel.  Thank you for your help.
Elmo

Comment: Perhaps the new sconce can have a switch added, similar to the existing.

Answer (score 1):

You have options, they actually make smart light bulbs you can power on and off with an app, but beyond that you can always find a wall scone made of aluminum and drill out a canopy switch, connect it to the positive on the fixture and problem solved. More invasive would be snaking a 14/2 to a future switch box location, install both black and white to the switch (mark the white wire with black tape to prevent  accidents in the future. Then you need to connect the feed wire (the positive wire that carrys the power to the light) to one side of the new wire, and the positive going to the light fixture to the other side of the new wire. Hope this helps

Comment: I hadn't thought of smart bulbs. That might be the way to go. I'll have to check prices though,  they used to be very expensive. Any experience with the rf switches I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the x10 in the past and it worked well as long as the circuit for the device was not over loaded. I found that using total wattage of less than 75% of the rated value they held up for many years. The other issue I found with them the range can be quite a bit shorter if installed in a home with steel path & plaster. From memory I thought the signal traveled on the wires but did find 1 case where the home base module was about 100' from the garage the garage light controls were intermittent until the base was closer possibly the different outlet the base was now on the same leg that the lights were on I don't remember but those were the only 2 problems I ever found with them. Note this was prior to LED lighting they powered fluorescent and incandescent lights.